# MySql: difference of times between closest rows

Tags: mysql, time, difference

I have this problem, I have table XYZ with these values:

product_id, user_name, event_type, event_time

ABCD123, user1, REPAIR, 2017-01-16 14:51:28

ABCD123, user1, REPAIR DONE, 2017-01-16 15:51:28

ABCD123, user1, REPAIR, 2017-01-16 16:51:28

ABCD123, user1, REPAIR DONE, 2017-01-16 18:51:28

How would be possible to get the time difference between first REPAIR DONE and first REPAIR and second REPAIR DONE and second REPAIR?
I tried this:

```
select a.product_id, a.user_name, b.event_time as start_time, a.event_time as end_time,  FORMAT((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, b.event_time, a.event_time)/3600),2) as difference   
FROM XYZ a  
join XYZ b
ON  a.product_id = b.product_id and a.user_name = b.user_name and a.event_type = 'REPAIR DONE' and b.event_type = 'REPAIR'
group by a.product_id, a.user_name 
order by a.event_time asc
```

but from some reason the result is this:

ABCD123, user1, difference 1 HOUR

ABCD123, user1, difference 4 HOURS

correct would be:

ABCD123, user1, difference 1 HOUR

ABCD123, user1, difference 2 HOURS

In other words, in second row I get result of the difference between first REPAIR and second REPAIR DONE instead second REPAIR and second REPAIR DONE.

Can anybody give me some advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like this_

```
    SELECT x1.products_id,
     x1.user_name, 
     CONCAT( 'difference ', HOUR(x2.event_time - x1.event_time),' Hour')
    FROM xyz x1
    LEFT JOIN xyz x2 ON x1.event_time < x2.event_time AND x2.event_type = 'REPAIR DONE'
    WHERE x1.event_type = 'REPAIR'
    ORDER BY x1.event_time;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I was not able to make your solution working, but could be problem on my side.

Comment: can you post a table with some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ the i will check it

Comment: Hello, I sent you sample data via e-mail, sqlfiddle seemed for me little confusing on the first look. I am sorry. Thanks for your try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select r.*, ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,r.event_time,rd.event_time))) as time_t
from ( (select * from xyz where event_event_type='REPAIR') as r 
JOIN (select * from xyz where event_type='REPAIR DONE') as rd 
ON(rd.event_time >r.event_time ) ) group by 
r.product_id,r.user_name,r.event_type,r.event_time having MIN(rd.event_time)
```

it shows proper output as per my understanding. As your problem looks interesting to me, that's why I give it a try, though I am pretty sure that my provided solution is not very good as per performance.But Just on a first try this is the output, you can think over it and can make the whole query perform better.

Comment: Thank you very much, Abhisek! Your solution really works. In table with all records I met some problem with duplicates, but this I will try to solve somehow.

Comment: Sorry, it was of course my mistake. With all records I must alter the on cause like ON(rd.event_time >r.event_time  and r.product_id = rd.product_id)

Comment: @Raymond so you mean that my answer is the solution for your problem

Comment: Yes, I tried to mark your answer like solution, but system wrote me, that it´s not visible for others, because I have less than 15 points of reputation.